# date-fns returns invalid date on safari

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm using `date-fns` to return some values as shown below:

```
import { format, formatDistance } from "date-fns";

var date = new Date("2019-03-06 00:00:00");
console.log(format(new Date(date), "dd MMM, y"));
```

It works fine on Chrome and returns `We Mar, y`

But returns `Invalid Date` in Safari.

I believe it's because the date ("2019-03-06 00:00:00") is not in ISO 8601 format. But this is the format I'm receiving from an endpoint. Is there any option to convert this to the right format and make it work on Safari?

Comment: Why are you parsing the date twice?

Comment: Maybe: `"2019-03-06 00:00:00".split(" ").join("T")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. You're relying on a nonstandard input format the first time you parse the date.
2. You're passing a `Date` into the `Date` constructor, which forces it to convert the date to a string, then parse the string.

I'd only parse it once, and use the [standard date/time format](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) when calling `new Date` the first time:

```
import { format, formatDistance } from "date-fns";

var date = new Date("2019-03-06T00:00:00");
// Note -----------------------^
console.log(format(date, "dd MMM, y"));
// No `new Date`   ^
```

Note that your string will be parsed as *local time* (on spec-compliant JavaScript engines¹) because it includes the time portion of the string. Unfortunately this varied after the format was added in ES2015, updated in ES2016, but where it's ended up is:

> When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

Since your string doesn't have a UTC offset (no `Z` or `+00:00` or similar), and does have a time, it's parsed in local time. (Again, on spec-compliant JavaScript engines¹).

My recommendation is either don't parse date strings with the built-in `Date` object, or make sure you always have a timezone indicator on the string if you do.

---

¹ [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) pointed out that Safari parses `new Date("2019-03-06T00:00:00")` as UTC. Sadly, this is [a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196894) in JavaScriptCore, Apple's JavaScript engine. It affects not only Safari, but Chrome on iOS as well (and probably any other iOS browser; I've tested Brave, Opera, and Dolphin), since Chrome has to use JavaScriptCore instead of its usual V8 on iOS because apps can't allocate executable memory, so JIT engines can't be used on iOS. But the V8 team have made an [interpreter-only version of V8](https://v8.dev/blog/jitless), so maybe Chrome (and Brave) on iOS will be updated to use that if it's fast enough.

Comment: Is there a way to convert `"2019-03-06 00:00:00"` to `"2019-03-06T00:00:00"` since I don't control what I get from the API?

Comment: @user1012181 - String replacement: `theDate = theDate.replace(/ /g, "T");`. You'll want to check whether what the API provides to you is meant to be UTC or local time. If it's meant to be UTC, add a `Z` at the end: `theDate = theDate.replace(/ /g, "T") + "Z";`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out

Comment: "*…it's parsed in local time.*". Nope, Safari's parser is brokent, `new Date("2019-03-06T00:00:00")` is parsed as UTC. :-(

Comment: @RobG - *"(on spec-compliant browsers)"* :-) (But I see I don't have that in both places.) I'm surprised Safari is *still* at variance with the spec, though, ugh. This is why I don't parse dates as strings without a timezone on them.

Comment: @RobG - Ugh, it's worse than that: It's not *Safari* per se (of course), it's JavaScriptCore, so it impacts Safari and also Chrome on iOS (since Chrome has to use JSC on iOS, because apps can't allocate executable memory -- but they may use V8's [interpreter-only mode](https://v8.dev/blog/jitless) instead at some point). The **really** irritating thing is that the format the spec *doesn't* define (`mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS`) is reliably parsed as local time across engines (and locales, despite being U.S.-specific): https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ojmh3fsv/2/ ***Sigh***

Comment: Shockingly, I couldn't find a bug report for it, so I [added one](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196894).

Comment: The Safari bug reporting system is pretty woeful. I reported some bugs years ago, as far as I know they aren't fixed. As of [*ECMAScript 2015*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-value), when passed a Date object the constructor no longer does the date -> string -> date thing, it just takes the time value. :-) I still like to use `new Date(+date)` though.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer for this can be, converting the date into the timestamp and value and feeding it to `format`

```
import { format, formatDistance } from "date-fns";

var date = new Date("2019-03-06").getTime();
console.log(format(new Date(date), "dd MMM, y"));
```